# how to deploy salesforce packages in appexchange

Tags: salesforce

how to deploy salesforce packages in appexchange

Comment: As per the (+1) answer this is a link right on the home page of the appexchange.  There seems to be a lot of (obvious) questions asked by this poster in quick succession and none accepted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put your own package on AppExchange marketplace, follow instructions from "[Publish](https://login.salesforce.com/?lt=appexchange&retURL=https%3A%2F%2Fsites.secure.force.com%2Fappexchange%2FpublisherHome&qs=promo)" link? It's available directly on front page, do you maybe have some detailed problems with it?

And if you mean installing apps from there - most of them have "Get it now" button and installation of trial version is pretty straightforward too.